# Can anyone help me out with this given problem no. 33

Tags: capacitor, homework

[image]

I'm confused as how charge would remain same as initial.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57202/discussion-on-question-by-sachin-chaudhary-can-anyone-help-me-out-with-this-give).

Answer (score 4):

This is a non-intuitive electrostatics problem and one that I believe the workbook author misunderstands (or else I do.) So I think this particular question, despite the OP's failure to show any work, is still worth using as a tool to illustrate some non-intuitive aspects involving electrostatics.

---

**HIDDEN ENERGY**

First off, let's provide a starting schematic and some identifiers:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcaCvm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The problem states first that \$C_1\$ and \$C_2\$ are separately charged with separate batteries. This is shown above on the left. Then these two capacitors are connected in series. This is shown above on the right.

The resulting voltage is the sum of the initial two voltages, or:

$$V_T=V_1+V_2=20\:\textrm{V}+30\:\textrm{V}=50\:\textrm{V}$$

The energy on the individual capacitors, before being connected in series, was:

$$\begin{array}{lcr}
V_1=20\:\textrm{V} & \quad Q_1=C_1\cdot V_1=20\:\mu\textrm{C} & \quad E_1=\frac{1}{2} C_1 \cdot V_1^2=200\:\mu\textrm{J}\\\\V_2=30\:\textrm{V} & \quad Q_2=C_2\cdot V_2=60\:\mu\textrm{C} & \quad E_2=\frac{1}{2} C_2\cdot V_2^2=900\:\mu\textrm{J}
\end{array}$$

Once series-connected, we then have:

$$\begin{align*}
V_T &= V_1+V_2=50\:\textrm{V}\\\\
C_T &= \frac{C_1\cdot C_2}{C_1+C_2}=\frac{2}{3}\:\mu\textrm{F}\\\\
Q_T &= C_T\cdot V_T = 33\frac{1}{3}\:\mu\textrm{C}\\\\
E_T &=\frac{1}{2} C_T V_T^2=833\frac{1}{3}\:\mu\textrm{J}
\end{align*}$$

Why isn't the following true?

$$E_T^{'}=E_1+E_2=1100\:\mu\textrm{J}$$

Well, the simple answer is that the difference between these two values, \$\vert E_T-E_T^{'}\vert\$, is ***hidden*** energy that is trapped within the new system and unavailable for use. (One could separate the capacitors again and use them independently. But that would be a different question.)

The *hidden* energy is due to the fact that each capacitor retains its initial charge, when connected in series. But any new change in charge in the series combination must change the charge in each capacitor individually, too, so that the change in charge in one is the same as the change in charge of the other, too. Let's delve into the details for a moment to provide a fuller explanation.

We already know the rule for combining series capacitors. But let's see why. To start, let's define what capacitance actually ***means*** and then let's see where that takes us. Capacitance is defined to mean this:

$$C_{eff} = \frac{\textrm{d}Q}{\textrm{d}V}$$

Now, suppose a change in charge occurs due to a short-duration, but constant current, \$I\$, that takes place from \$t_1\$ to \$t_2\$. The change in time is \$\Delta t=t_2-t_1\$ and the change in charge is \$\Delta Q=I\cdot \Delta t\$. Suppose the original charge on \$C_1\$ is \$Q_1\$ and the original charge on \$C_2\$ is \$Q_2\$:

$$\begin{split}
Q_1^{'} &= Q_1+\Delta Q\\\\
V_1^{'} &= \frac{Q_1^{'}}{C_1} \\\\&= \frac{Q_1+\Delta Q}{C_1}\\\\&=V_1+\frac{\Delta Q}{C_1}
\end{split}\quad\quad\quad\begin{split}
Q_2^{'} &= Q_2+\Delta Q\\\\
V_2^{'} &= \frac{Q_2^{'}}{C_2}\\\\&= \frac{Q_2+\Delta Q}{C_2}\\\\&=V_2+\frac{\Delta Q}{C_2}
\end{split}$$

And,

$$\begin{align*}
V_T^{'} &= V_1^{'}+V_2^{'}\\\\
&=V_1+\frac{\Delta Q}{C_1}+V_2+\frac{\Delta Q}{C_2}\\\\
&=V_1+V_2 +\frac{\Delta Q}{C_1}+\frac{\Delta Q}{C_2}\\\\
&= V_T+\frac{\Delta Q}{C_1}+\frac{\Delta Q}{C_2}\\\\
\Delta V &= V_T^{'}-V_T = \frac{\Delta Q}{C_1}+\frac{\Delta Q}{C_2}
\end{align*}$$

The effective *total* capacitance found from this differential perspective is, as expected:

$$\begin{align*}
C_T &=\frac{\Delta Q}{\Delta V}\\\\
&= \frac{\Delta Q}{\frac{\Delta Q}{C_1}+\frac{\Delta Q}{C_2}}\\\\
&= \frac{1}{\frac{1}{C_1}+\frac{1}{C_2}}
\end{align*}$$

Nothing magic here. It's just a re-demonstration of why series capacitors combine in this way (so that there is no argument about it in the following, continuation below.)

We also know that the initial voltages will sum, when capacitors are placed in series. So, given the above description about how two series capacitors combine and given that the initial voltages add, we can now compute the effective charge on the combination as:

$$\begin{align*}
Q_T&=C_T\cdot V_T\\\\
&= \frac{1}{\frac{1}{C_1}+\frac{1}{C_2}} \cdot \left(V_1+V_2\right)\\\\
&= \frac{C_1\cdot C_2}{C_1+C_2} \cdot \left(\frac{Q_1}{C_1}+\frac{Q_2}{C_2}\right)\\\\
&= \frac{1}{C_1+C_2} \cdot \left(C_2\cdot Q_1+C_1\cdot Q_2\right)\\\\
&= \frac{C_2\cdot Q_1+C_1\cdot Q_2}{C_1+C_2}
\end{align*}$$

Note here that if \$Q_1=Q_2\$ then \$Q_T=Q_1+Q_2\$, but that in all other cases it's a value between the two initial values of charge.

(This is just the same result as if you had a voltage divider pair of resistors, between two voltages, and wanted to know the voltage at the middle node. The initial values for \$Q_1\$ and for \$Q_2\$ are like the separating voltages in that resistive divider, and the capacitors are like the resistors in that divider.)

The point here is to provide some explanation about why some of the energy may appear to be hidden in a series chain of initially charged, but differently charged capacitors.

The hidden portion of the energy is:

$$E_{hidden}=\frac{1}{2}\left[\sum_{i=1}^N C_i V_i^2-C_T\sum_{i=1}^N V_i^2\right]$$

where \$C_T\$ is the equivalent series capacitance, computed in the usual way shown above.

So, in this case, the ***available*** energy of the newly combined system is \$833\frac{1}{3}\:\mu\textrm{J}\$. (In effect, the difference \$E_{hidden}=266\frac{2}{3}\:\mu\textrm{J}\$ has been trapped or hidden away due to the new series arrangement.) And the available charge is now \$33\frac{1}{3}\:\mu\textrm{C}\$.

Again, take note that this available charge is more than was originally available on \$C_1\$ but less than was originally available on \$C_2\$. (Just as predicted.) Had the charge been the same on both capacitors, then the total available charge would have been undiminished and would have been unchanged in the series combination. (Also, as predicted.)

So, for example, if there were \$60\:\mu\textrm{C}\$ available on both \$C_1\$ and \$C_2\$, then the total series voltage would have been \$90\:\textrm{V}\$ and the total available charge would have still been \$60\:\mu\textrm{C}\$. But when the initial charges are different, then the available charge on the combination has to be adjusted.

---

**ENERGY LOST DUE TO HEAT AND/OR RADIATED ENERGY**

At this point in the question, something new happens:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feu9lK.png)</sup>

On the left, the above schematic shows the circumstances just prior to connecting the new, uncharged capacitor in parallel to the prior series system. Namely, at \$t=0^{-}\$. On the right, it shows the circumstances afterwards (at \$t=\infty\$.)

In between, at and following \$t= 0\$, there will be rapidly changing voltages and currents as the charges move around and re-distribute themselves since the initial voltages are different and must find a new equilibrium state. The question now asks us to provide the charge which is present across \$C_1\$ in the above circuit on the right at \$t=\infty\$ (equilibrium.)

Here, work is done. I won't replicate here the work shown at [this hyperphysics page](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/capeng2.html#c4). But the gist required for a better capacitor model is presented there. The upshot is that energy is lost. Most of this energy is usually lost through heat. But circumstances can be arranged to reduce that loss due to heating and to increase the loss due to electromagnetic radiation. Either way, there's no escaping the loss.

So the rule to apply here is charge conservation. We know the available total charge, since it's been computed above, and this charge is re-distributed in the usual way across the newly formed total capacitance in this new parallel combination. In the end, we find:

$$\begin{align*}
Q_T &= 33\frac{1}{3}\:\mu\textrm{C}\\\\
C_T &= C_3 + \frac{C_1\cdot C_2}{C_1+C_2}=2\frac{2}{3}\:\mu\textrm{F}\\\\
V_T &= \frac{Q_T}{C_T}=12.5\:\textrm{V}\\\\
E_T &=\frac{1}{2} C_T V_T^2=208\frac{1}{3}\:\mu\textrm{J}
\end{align*}$$

We had started with a total of \$833\frac{1}{3}\:\mu\textrm{J}\$, available in the series combination of \$C_1\$ and \$C_2\$, and now find that we only have \$208\frac{1}{3}\:\mu\textrm{J}\$ of it still available. The rest was lost to heat and/or EM radiation and is gone.

At \$t=+\infty\$, the charge has finally been re-distributed and we can find that:

$$\begin{array}{lcr}
V_3 = V_T = 12.5\:\textrm{V} & Q_3 = C_3 V_3 = 25\:\mu\textrm{C} & E_3 = \frac{1}{2} C_3 V_3^2=156\frac{1}{4} \:\mu\textrm{J}\\\\
V_{1,2} = V_T = 12.5\:\textrm{V} & Q_{1,2}= C_{1,2} V_{1,2} = 8\frac{1}{3}\:\mu\textrm{C} & E_{1,2}=\frac{1}{2} C_{1,2} V_{1,2}^2=52\frac{1}{12}\:\mu\textrm{J}
\end{array}$$

UPDATE: I'd made an earlier mistake in apportioning charge back to \$C_1\$ and \$C_2\$ (which amounted to assuming that the charge is the same on the two series capacitor after the parallel capacitor was added.) Trevor caught the flawed assumption. (Given all the balderdash here, that's incredible!)

The motion of charge from the series pair of \$C_1\$ and \$C_2\$ is just the newly added charge on \$C_3\$. So \$\Delta Q= Q_3=25\:\mu\textrm{C}\$. This amount must be subtracted from each of the series capacitors. So:

$$\begin{array}{lr}
Q_1=20\:\mu\textrm{C} - \Delta Q=-5\:\mu\textrm{C} & V_1=\frac{Q_1}{C_1}=-5\:\textrm{V}\\\\
Q_2=60\:\mu\textrm{C} - \Delta Q=35\:\mu\textrm{C} & V_2=\frac{Q_2}{C_2}=17.5\:\textrm{V}\end{array}$$

This is the final answer, I think.

---

**RESULT**

And so, we now find the answer. The value for the charge across \$C_1\$, in equilibrium at \$t=+\infty\$, is \$-5\:\mu\textrm{C}\$.

Here is a spice simulation to demonstrate the result:

[image]

This answer is still not found in the problem's offerings.

Comment: WOW.. There should be a prize for longest and most complete answer of the week :)

Comment: @Trevor Must be a HAT for that!

Comment: @Trevor Any criticisms? I don't think I missed anything. But the answer was not found in the workbook, either. I think the author should not have been writing problems for it. But I could be wrong, too.

Comment: information overload comes to mind.... and I am still not sure of the original question LOL.

Comment: @Trevor The question isn't intuitive for most people and, frankly, the workbook author didn't get it right. That's evidence why this needs to be carefully laid out and flayed apart. I also wanted to expose all my sources of possible erroneous assumptions along the way. Regardless, thanks for the input.

Comment: I dunno, I have always had a hard time with capacitors and have been scratching my head and scribbling for the past hour.. the part that says "The hidden energy is due to the fact that each capacitor retains its initial charge, when connected in series." bothers me.

Comment: @Trevor: Good. It should bother you. You can see how I've set it up though, in the end. The equation \$Q_T=\frac{Q_2\cdot C_1+Q_1\cdot C_2}{C_1+C_2}\$ provides the exact description for computing the resulting usable charge. There is another way to examine this using electric field intensity descriptions, which I avoided adding. One way to summarize it is that there is some imbalancing "stress" that results from unequal Coulomb charges.

Comment: Yup as far as I can see your equations make sense... kind of.

Comment: OH wait..... I just calculated 5uC.. lemme explain in an answer

Comment: Crap I can't add one

Comment: Lemme try here... I used the formulas for initial Q for both caps got 80uC. Then Calculated Cseries = 2/3. Adding the 2u QParallel = 2.66667. Then I simply multiply the 20uC from C1 by .66667/2.6667. Hey presto 5uC.

Comment: @Trevor Yeah. That may be the source for that answer on the workbook. But that's not how it works. If you actually had \$80\:\mu\textrm{C}\$ of charge, then the voltage across them would be \$V=\frac{80\:\mu\textrm{C}}{667\:\textrm{nF}} = 120\:\textrm{V}\$ (before the final cap is added, I mean.) And you ***know*** you don't have that. Besides, the OP says the workbook author wants \$20\:\mu\textrm{C}\$ and had your answer given as wrong.

Comment: Dunno but I am back working it too and it seems right

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57271/discussion-between-trevor-and-jonk).

Comment: @Trevor Thanks so much for the time. I do now see my mistake!  As you said, I didn't re-distribute the charge. Thanks again for the time you offered, and thoughts. I'll correct the page.

Comment: @Trevor I added a correction that is (again) different. I didn't take the ratios to remain the same. You were correct to change my error in assuming the charges were identical (which was totally wrong.) I still need to load the spreadsheet software, so it will be a delay before I get a change to see your work, yet. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, as always the test I did happens to work out by chance. I did a new spreadsheet with this method and it seems consistant for a variety of initial values so I think we cracked it :) Though that still doesn't explain the discrepancy in the test...

Comment: @Trevor No, it doesn't explain that. (Thanks so much for the time, by the way. Undeserved, but still very much appreciated.)

Comment: I'm still not convinced though. And some internet searches have resulted in a lot of mixed results. I even came up with a scenario that's keeps the 20uC charge on C1 but I can't really wrap my head around how it can do that physically and the model can end up with more energy that you started with which makes no sense. It almost makes me want to go out and buy the caps and do the test and see what really happens.

Comment: @Trevor Okay. But this is theoretical and real capacitors aren't. I should go back to the electric field description at the physical level, including the opposing-aligned dielectric dipoles formed in the dielectric, and take it from a physics-only perspective. I think that will get me there. I'll have to review the material. However, I know I failed to think clearly about the "equal charges" approach I took at first and I thank you very much for catching that idiocy of mine. It was obviously wrong from the start and I should have caught it, myself.

Comment: @Trevor The approach I took above does make sense to me, holding short of the physics for now, as the charge ***must*** transfer. And I don't believe there is ***any*** physical reason to imagine that the charge ratios would stay the same, let alone the same sign. I do believe there is argument that the transfer would take place as I mentioned, latest. But the reality will be a matter of physics and the deeper, physical models which, when integrated over the large populations, will exactly reflect the behavior we'll observe. So that's the next place to head.

Comment: @Trevor I just made spice do it for me. Yes, it turns out that \$C_1\$'s voltage goes to \$-5\:\textrm{V}\$ in the simulation.

Comment: Cool I was trying it with the simulator in here... but it did not give the same result... not really surprising though.. it is a pretty sad simulator.

Comment: @Trevor Mike at Linear is a really good guy, dedicated to making spice available to everyone (despite a marketing department unwilling to fund a bigger library of parts for it using competing products.) Linear's LTspice is actually the same product they use for IC wafer designs -- so it has to be very good and has to support the latest in modeling techniques. We are the beneficiaries of those efforts, as Mike doesn't want to (and isn't asked to) maintain two Spice programs. It is FREE!

Comment: Yes, I should download that. I tried LT but got frustrated with it wanting me to use their parts. Glad you verified the answer though, as I said it made sense, but without running a verification it was still just interpretation. Great work.

Comment: @Trevor I went back to "Matter & Interactions" and found physical justification for what I did here. (required doing integrals!) So I feel a lot better. Thanks so much for catching a glaring error and taking the time to hammer it in so that I took note! Regarding LTspice: I can provide (upload to a site) a lot of useful models. There is also the Yahoo group that caters to developing new models for it. And of course, many models are often provided by manufacturer sites, too. But yes, it's a pain and there is a learning curve in getting models. But the price is right if you can get past that.

Comment: :) I reinstalled it.. Now all I need to do is take the time to play with it.... (easier said than done). You are welcome btw, I enjoyed the challenge. BTW I think the originator that wrote the test thought of the circuit as the charge moving in buckets from R2 to R3 through R1 model, with that idea the charge on R1 would not change... But that model is seriously wrong, despite it being quoted by many. Unfortunately, mathematically it works to produce STABLE but (WRONG) results under certain initial conditions, which just makes matters worse.

Comment: @Trevor I recognized this problem right away as *interesting*. Which is why I spent time on it. It touched on a weakness in my own understanding and I felt, instinctively, that it was worth pursuing (if only for my sake.) Turns out that it has deepened my understanding. And I'm glad for that (and this is why I owe you so much more for what you gave me by taking your time and challenging what I'd done.) Regarding LTspice, I have THOUSANDS of BJT models, MOSFET models, etc. I'll ZIP all that stuff up and write some web page of explanations to get started quickly using it and post it here.

Comment: :) Thanks that would help, and yes, the "puzzle" got me intrigued, and just a tad frustrated.. too.

Comment: Pity they put it on hold... it is actually a good question once you get past the obvious home work part.

Comment: Might actually be worth posting as a new question and pasting in your answer.

Comment: @Trevor I cobbled up a quick page just to get some details across and to provide a big library of OnSemi discrete part models. I'll be adding a lot when time allows: http://infinitefactors.org/adhoc/LTSpice.html

Comment: Cool thanks.... see my comment up 2 lines... It would be a shame If this question gets deleted after all that work.

Comment: @Trevor Hehe. Okay. Can you propose a good question that will fairly involve these details? I know the starting point would be a knock-off of this question. But can you propose something even better formulated, perhaps? Just asking, if you feel up to thinking any more on this. I'll give it a little thought to see if I can improve the question, regardless. Just want to open it up, in case you want to add anything.

Comment: @Trevor I also think I'll need to expand on the \$\int_0^Q V\:\textrm{d} q\$ work required part. Just a link isn't enough for a proper answer.

Comment: I could but it's better if you do for brownie points... and answer it yourself.. weird SO thing..  lemme think about the format though....

Comment: I'd call it "pre-charged series capacitor behavior". Show and describe the setup and explain the paradox between charge movement and current movement and hidden energy. Then ask about how to calculate the final voltages on the capacitors when the switch closes.

Comment: @Trevor Sounds good. Sidebar: I don't really care about brownie points. I got what I wanted, already. Understanding it better than I did before. That's the gold for me and I already have it handed to me on a platter.

Comment: @Trevor The rest is just social-caste crap based on sheep looking at meaningless rating numbers and imagining it makes anything I say any better (which it does not.) That means very little to me. I'm a hobbyist only, with exactly zero electronics training, and having people imagine they should falsely trust me for some silly rating number scares me a lot. It should be about how I think about the world, and not some number nor even my conclusions. It's the process, not the end. As this question itself points out so well.

Comment: :) That is very true, I don't really care about the brownie points either, but since they are there ...

Comment: @Trevor I got my conclusions wrong here!! But I was thinking *about* the question in a useful way. Which is the thing to learn from/about. Not the exact conclusions, which of course can be wrong because of a slip-up (I certainly did slip.) We learn from the thinking processes. Even the best of us can be very wrong in our conclusions. But we learn the better tools by finding how good people think about the world. Not about how they necessarily conclude in the end.

Comment: That's very true... It's also my basis for believing any commentary on a question is good, whether it agrees or not. It adds perspectives that may not have been considered.

Comment: @Trevor That's a good point. Commentary helps expose thinking processes, so that they can be examined and learned from... Hmm. Oh, well. I have an appointment to attend so will be away for some hours now. But back after 4-5 hours. Until then... Thanks so much for the time you offered me.